# Windows cmd finding fully qualified path name

Tags: windows, cmd

Hi i was just wondering if any knew how to find the fully qualified path name for say Paint or other programs?

Answer (score 0):

Where does something similar to "which". Looks to see what would be run, if you ran the application from the commandline.

```
H:\>where.exe mspaint.exe
C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe
```

This will only find things on the path.

A similar command in powershell does the same thing -'get-command'.

You could scour the file system using a find, eg.

```
C:\>dir /b /s c:\ |find "mspaint.exe"
c:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe
c:\Windows\System32\en-GB\mspaint.exe.mui
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\mspaint.exe
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-GB\mspaint.exe.mui
...
...
```

which will locate things that are not on the path (and everything else besides)

Comment: what about for finding non windows prorams like google chrome?

Comment: the where command finds executables on your path, if Chrome is there, you should be able to find it -it is not just for Windows applications. Otherwise, you have to use "find".

Comment: no need for `find`. `dir` can do it for you: `dir /s /b c:\mspaint.exe` ( "c:\" is the start path for searching, so maybe better: `dir /s /b %systemdrive%\mspaint.exe`)